# Infinity is stored in number column

Tags: java, oracle, numbers, infinity

I have a table structure like below:

```
PROD(PROD_ID NUMBER,PROD_NAME VARCHAR2(100), MATCH_SCORE NUMBER)
```

Based upon some calculation (backend logic which is not part of our application) sometimes Infinity is getting stored in `MATCH_SCORE`.

The question is why it is allowing Infinity in a `NUMBER` column (`MATCH_SCORE`).

I've tried to get Infinity into the column myself:

```
INSERT INTO PROD VALUES(1,"PEN",1.0F/0); -- Doesn't work
INSERT INTO PROD VALUES(1,"PEN",BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY); -- Doesn't work.
```

The [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313) says:

> The following numbers can be stored in a NUMBER column:
>
> - Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10-130 to 9.99...9 x 10125 with up to 38 significant digits
> - Negative numbers from -1 x 10-130 to 9.99...99 x 10125 with up to 38 significant digits
> - Zero
> - Positive and negative infinity **(generated only by importing from an Oracle Database, Version 5)**

*(my emphasis)*

We are not migrated from version 5, it is still happening in Oracle 11.

**Java MCVE illustrating how issue arises:**

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test_infinity ( value NUMBER );
```

Java:

```
try {
  Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" );
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
    "username",
    "password"
  );

  PreparedStatement st = con.prepareCall( "INSERT INTO test_infinity VALUES ( :value )" );
  ((OraclePreparedStatement)st).setNUMBERAtName( "value", NUMBER.posInf() );
  st.execute();
  st.close();
  con.close();
}
catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex ){}
```

Comment: Well what makes you think it *shouldn't* allow infinity? You've quoted Oracle documentation saying that that's a valid value for `NUMBER`...

Comment: Where's Java involved?

Comment: @JonSkeet: then why insert statements are failing?

Comment: @Thomas : Our application trying to read like this rs.getDoubleValue('MATCH_SCORE'); that's it exception.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay, this still as nothing to do with Java ... Your server is running on Unix ? You don't add this TAG either ;)

Comment: Ah, I see that it's the "only" bit which is about migrating. My guess is that that documentation is inaccurate, and that drivers can insert infinity directly. But it sounds like the underlying problem is in the code that's performing the insert.

Comment: Added a [MCVE] to illustrate how the issue can arise via Java when it does not seem to be possible to insert Infinity via SQL statements.